# How to delete more than one row in a table? Using a single code, without two times typing execute and conditions inside

Tags: python, sqlite, where-clause, sql-delete

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db') # connectiong to database or creating new if table does 
not exist
cursor = conn.cursor() # allows python to use sql commands

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fruits( #creating table
code TEXT PRIMARY KEY, # text data-type, primary key -constraint
name TEXT,
price FLOAT);
''')
conn.commit() # saves all changes made
fruit_list = [('1','blackberry', 300.00),('2','raspberry', 250.00), ('3','bananas', 150.00), 
('4','strawberry', 200.00)] #list of tuples
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO Fruits VALUES(?,?,?)', fruit_list) # inserting data into table
```

### cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM Fruits WHERE name='blackberry'""") cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM Fruits WHERE price='150.00'""")

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Fruits')
show_all = cursor.fetchall()
for e in show_all:
print('code: {} | name: {} | price {}'.format(e[0],e[1],e[2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine all your conditions in the `WHERE` clause with the logical operator `OR` in a single statement:

```
DELETE 
FROM Fruits 
WHERE name='blackberry' OR price='150.00'
```

Comment: I was trying with operator 'and' . It didnt work. Thanks.

Comment: @forpass got it :)